# Singleton in Android Studio - Not Working

Tags: java, android, singleton

I am trying to implement the Singleton patterns, but I am facing some issues.

I have an array list that contains some objects. And I would like to have a single copy of that array while the program is running, and would like to access that array from anywhere in my program. When I try to do that using the code below, I get a null reference object error

I have tried a variety of ways to implements this, and I posted below only one variety to help clarify what I am trying to achieve.

```
public class Singleton{

       static private Singleton singleton = null;
       private ArrayList<Object> array;

       private void Singleton(){
       }

       public static Singleton getInstance(){
              if(singleton == null)
                   singleton = new Singleton();
              return singleton;
       }

       public void addObject(Object object){
             array.add(object);
       }

}

public class callSingleton(){

       public void callSingleton(){
               Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
               Object object = new Object();
               singleton.addObject(object);
       }
}
```

Comment: Whats not working? array never initialize . Its a NulPointerExcception. Be specific on Your question

Comment: Initializing the array fixed the problem. But how do I initialize data in the array once it is created? For example, suppose I want to load a data from a file to the array once it is created, how should I do that? Initializing data in the array when the constructor is called failed because the data does not exist once I call the singleton object from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to init your array;

```
private ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
```